# Mounting Windows local folder into pod

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop, kubernetes-pvc

I'm running a Ubuntu container with SQL Server in my local Kubernetes environment with Docker Desktop on a Windows laptop.
Now I'm trying to mount a local folder (`C:\data\sql`) that contains database files into the pod.
For this, I configured a persistent volume and persistent volume claim in Kubernetes, but it doesn't seem to mount correctly. I don't see errors or anything, but when I go into the container using `docker exec -it` and inspect the data folder, it's empty. I expect the files from the local folder to appear in the mounted folder 'data', but that's not the case.

Is something wrongly configured in the PV, PVC or pod?

Here are my yaml files:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: dev-customer-db-pv
  labels:
    type: local
    app: customer-db
    chart: customer-db-0.1.0
    release: dev
    heritage: Helm
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /C/data/sql
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: dev-customer-db-pvc
  labels:
    app: customer-db
    chart: customer-db-0.1.0
    release: dev
    heritage: Helm
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
```

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dev-customer-db
  labels:
    ufo: dev-customer-db-config
    app: customer-db
    chart: customer-db-0.1.0
    release: dev
    heritage: Helm
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: customer-db
      release: dev
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: customer-db
        release: dev
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: dev-customer-db-pv
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: dev-customer-db-pvc
      containers:
      - name: customer-db
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        volumeMounts:
          - name: dev-customer-db-pv
            mountPath: /data
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: dev-customer-db-config
          - secretRef:
              name: dev-customer-db-secrets
```

At first, I was trying to define a volume in the pod without PV and PVC, but then I got access denied errors when I tried to read files from the mounted data folder.

```yaml
spec:
      volumes:
        - name: dev-customer-db-data
          hostPath:
            path: C/data/sql
      containers:
        ...        
        volumeMounts:
          - name: dev-customer-db-data
            mountPath: data
```

I've also tried to Helm install with `--set volumePermissions.enabled=true` but this didn't solve the access denied errors.

Comment: Are you able to create persistent volume? What does `kubectl get pv dev-customer-db-pv` and `kubectl get pvc dev-customer-db-pvc` show?

Comment: kubectl describe pv:
Name:            dev-customer-db-pv
Labels:          <removed for brevity>
Annotations:     <removed for brevity>
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:
Status:          Available
Claim:
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        1Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /C/data/sql
    HostPathType:
Events:            <none>

Comment: kubectl describe pvc:
...
Capacity:      100Mi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Events:
  Type    Reason                 Age   From
Message
...  Normal  Provisioning           13m   docker.io/hostpath_storage-provisioner_...  
External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/dev-customer-db-pvc"
  Normal  ProvisioningSucceeded  13m   docker.io/hostpath_storage-provisioner_7da78fbd-f930-4d1d-b9ad-66b6ddbac442  Successfully provisioned volume pvc-d017adcc-462e-4d10-aead-cf75d83000db

Comment: @ngruson What are you using for Docker Desktop - WSL 2 or Hyper-V?

Comment: I'm using WSL2. I'm on the latest version of Docker Desktop (4.1.1, 69879)

Comment: Based on this info from [GitHub for Docker](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5325#issuecomment-567481915) there is no support hostpath volumes in WSL 2. So, below workaround that I tested. I changed spec.volumes for Deployment:    
      ```volumes:
        - name: dev-customer-db-pv
          hostPath: 
            path: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/data/sql
            type: Directory```
No need for PV and PVC in that case (removed them previously).
[About configuring hostPath on Kubernetes site](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath-configuration-example)

Comment: I do see a `run` folder in the pod, but it doesn't have a subfolder `desktop`. `/run/mount` is empty. Should I do anything to get the desktop folder in the pod?

Comment: In my initial question, I also stated I tried something like that without PV/PVC. Then the files show up but I get access denied errors. SQL is also not able to attach the database in that case.

Comment: You can see your files in `data` folder in pod, since your `mountPath: /data` And in addition for my previous comment - we need just to add `/run/desktop/mnt/host` to your initial path on your host `/c/data/sql`. That is why `path:/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/data/sql`

Comment: Yes, it works with the last reply of Andrew. Using the hostpath `/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/data/sql`, the database files can be used inside the SQL container.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on this info from [GitHub for Docker](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5325#issuecomment-567481915) there is no support hostpath volumes in WSL 2.

Thus, **next workaround can be used**.

We need just to append `/run/desktop/mnt/host` to the initial path on the host `/c/data/sql`.  No need for PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim in this case - just remove them.

I changed `spec.volumes` for Deployment according to [information about hostPath configuration on Kubernetes site](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath-configuration-example):

```
volumes:
- name: dev-customer-db-pv
  hostPath:
    path: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/data/sql
    type: Directory
```

After applying these changes, the files can be found in `data` folder in the pod, since `mountPath: /data`

Comment: Worked for me after I adjusted volumeMounts: /data/db and subPath: data